# QRCode attribute from qrcode python module doens't work

Tags: python

I'm attempting to study qrcode python module, but i'm coming across "phantom things" seemly, sorry.
Suddenly, the 'qrcode' module has no QRCode attribute, that would must, according documentation.

There are several topics about, all of these agree about this attribute. The filename is "example.py", by the way.

Can, anybody, please, enlight it?

```
import qrcode

qr = qrcode.QRCode()
```

```
 qr = qrcode.QRCode()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                       '?
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'qrcode' has no attribute 'QRCode' (most likely due to a circular import). Did you mean: 'qrcode'?
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not initilizing the `QRCode` class properly. The correct way to initialize the `QRCode` class is as below:

```
import qrcode

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=1,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
    box_size=10,
    border=2,
)

### add your data
qr.add_data('Some random amount of data')
qr.make(fit=True)

img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")

### save the generated code
img.save("random_qr.png")

print("type of the image: ",type(img))
```

Output:

```
type of the image:  <class 'qrcode.image.pil.PilImage'>
```

[image]

##### Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for response, but no. The issue persists.
I already ran with these parameters earlier

Comment: what's the filename of your script? don't keep it as `qrcode.py`, change to any other name, most probably this is what is creating the circular import issue

Comment: Not at all. The IA gave it back: 
"o problema pode ocorrer se você estiver importando o módulo tkinter em um arquivo que também está sendo importado pelo módulo tkinter. Isso cria um loop de importação circular e resulta no erro que você está vendo.". 
The same happens with Tk() from tkinter.

Comment: this is because, some of your scripts are named same as the module.py you're trying to import. thats what is causing the circular import issue. rename your scripts to something else

Comment: you already said, your qrcode script is named as example.py so most likely it's your tkinter script that is named wrongly

Comment: Well, ok. It worked out! Thanks.